# How do I subtract multiple dates?

Tags: sql, oracle

[An image of the Discharge date and admission date in which i am supposed to subtract as (discharge date – admitted
date) +1 .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi88x.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said - subtract and sum. Sample data in lines #1 - 5, query begins at line #6.

```
SQL> with test (who, admission_date, discharge_date) as
  2    (select 'Leslie', date '2010-09-13', date '2010-09-25' from dual union all
  3     select 'Leslie', date '2014-09-03', date '2014-09-21' from dual union all
  4     select 'Leslie', date '2015-12-03', date '2015-12-14' from dual
  5    )
  6  select who, sum(discharge_date - admission_date + 1) total_days
  7  from test
  8  group by who;

WHO    TOTAL_DAYS
------ ----------
Leslie         44

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was struggling with this for quite a while. Truely appreciate it!!